Error: self-signed certificate || code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT' || Angular 18
When call a GET api from Angular 18 to .Net Core 8 Web API. First time Data Fetched but after reload that page a error occur. [cause]: Error: self-signed certificate && code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'.enter image description here
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
  provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
  provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration()
  ]
};

 bindCategory() {
    debugger;
    this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe({
      next: (response: ApiResult<CategoryMasterDTO>) => {
        this.categoryApiResult = response;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Error fetching categories', err);
        this.categoryApiResult = { dataList: [], result: false, message: 'Error fetching categories' };
      }
    });
  }

Call a GET API from angular 18 to .net core8 web api. there is error occor.  [cause]: Error: self-signed certificate && code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'.

Could you kindly check this thread ?
